# Compatibility between translate(-50%, -50%) and animations

Tags: css, animation

Having the following css:

```
.screen {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.card {
    width: 200px; background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes kf_anim {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(315deg);

    }

    100% {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}

.card_anim {
    animation: kf_anim 0.5s forwards;
}
```

If I do

```
<div class="screen">
    <div class="card">content</div>
</div>
```

I get a horizontally-and-vertically centered div, which is what I want. But if I add the animation

```
<div class="screen">
    <div class="card card_anim">content</div>
</div>
```

The animation is performed but the div is no longer centered, i.e., the translate(-50%, -50%) is overridden.

I tried adding `translate(-50%, -50%)` next to the `rotateY` in the keyframes, but then the animation does not work properly.

How can I solve this, assuming that I can't know the width and height?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n5pma29m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the css combined like below

```
 @keyframes kf_anim {
        0% {
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(315deg);

        }

        100% {
            transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(360deg);
        }
    }
```

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n5pma29m/1/)

Comment: amazing... I thought I already tried this but I was setting the rotate before the translate and the result is completely different. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosNavarro the animation starts in the order we mentioned (in our case first translate and then rotate executes simultaneously) ,you can have a look at this page for tranform propery and its values [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS properties are not “additive” – you are *overwriting* the previous transform value in your animation.

You need to specify the translate part in your keyframes as well:

```
@keyframes kf_anim {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(315deg);

    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
```